# Orthonormal basis on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset H$ and $x\in H$ such that $\lVert x_{n}\rVert=\lVert x\rVert=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose also that $\lvert 1-<x,x_n>\rvert\leq\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now my question is if the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis in $H$, i.e if it is orthogonal and total?  Does anyone have any ideas how to investigate this?

Comment: Of course not.  For a real Hilbert space, $\langle x, x_n\rangle$ is $\cos\theta_n$ where $\theta_n$ is the angle between $x$ and $x_n$.  You can build an example even in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with vectors $x_n$ converging to $x$ with $\theta_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.